# networkx remove node attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, networkx

i have attached numpy-array to nodes in a networkx graph. How to store the graph in gexf-format on disk? (without the numpy vector, as its just something intermediate...)

```
def create():
    G = nx.Graph()
    for i in range(256):
        G.add_node(i, vector=np.arange(20))
    for i in range(1,20):
        for j in range(1,256, 10):
            G.add_edge(i,j)

    temp = tempfile.mktemp(suffix=".gexf")
    print("dumping G = (V: %s, E: %s) to disk %s"
        % (len(G.nodes()), len(G.edges()), temp))
    nx.write_gexf(G, temp)
```

However, this breaks. I'm new to python, but to me it seems like the ndarray is not serializable?! So, how to tell networkx to ignore that node attribute?

```
File "...lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\gexf.py", line 430, in add_attributes
    attr_id = self.get_attr_id(make_str(k), self.xml_type[val_type],
KeyError: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by removing the property "vector" from the data items:

```
for (n,d) in G.nodes(data=True):
    del d["vector"]
```

full MWE:

```
def create():
    G = nx.Graph()
    for i in range(256):
        G.add_node(i, vector=np.arange(20))
    for i in range(1,20):
        for j in range(1,256, 10):
            G.add_edge(i,j)

    temp = tempfile.mktemp(suffix=".gexf")
    print("dumping G = (V: %s, E: %s) to disk %s"
        % (len(G.nodes()), len(G.edges()), temp))
    for (n,d) in G.nodes(data=True):
        del d["vector"]
    nx.write_gexf(G, temp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a library like the native [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), or [`h5py`](http://www.h5py.org/) for HDF5, to serialize your graph object. For example you can do:

```
import pickle

with open("pickle_file", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(create(), f)
```

The pickled graph can be loaded back into Python by:

```
with open("pickle_file", "rb") as f:
    G = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: uhm, but then i wont be able to load it in gephi ;)

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question ;)

Comment: i updated the question. so, thanks for pointing that one out.